# How to fix npx create React start up screen on terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

I have no idea what's going on here. Earlier today I was able to create React apps perfectly fine.

After typing in `npx create-react-app <name>` everything would load, and it would show me the basic npx commands.

But now, this weird output is showing up and I have no idea what to do:

[image]

P.S. I have a 2017 Macbook Pro running Catalina 10.15.3

Answer (score 0):

you must ensure you have free space in your device

If it doesn't work for you, if you can explain the problem better

Comment: yes I fixed that issue as well, still no luck. I wish I could explain it better, but the issue is i'm not quite sure what's going on myself, I am new to React

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with fsevents. Try adding this to your package.json:

```
{
  "resolutions": {
    "**/**/fsevents": "^1.2.9"
  }

}
```

Delete yarn.lock and run yarn install again. Or if you're using npm, delete package-lock.json, run npm install.

Comment: But I never used yarn, I used npm

Comment: if you can restart your device  and ensure you have free space

Comment: Also, why would that have changed? I didn't do anything different from this morning when it was working fine

Comment: it happened with me

Comment: I have about 60gb available and have restarted my laptop and everything.